# Separating multiple XML results in an XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm retrieving an xml document that has multiple items and I want to be able to query the XDocument such that I can separate the results. So for example, I'm running this query:"http://mymovieapi.com/?title=argo&type=xml&plot=simple&episode=1&limit=2&yg=0&mt=none&lang=en-US&offset=&aka=simple&release=simple&business=0&tech=0". This is a query against the IMDB movie database and I'm searching for the film Argo. The result set looks like the following (abridged) XML, which shows that there are two films named argo:

```
<IMDBDocumentList>
  <item>
    <rated>R</rated>
    <actors>
      <item>Ben Affleck</item>
      <item>Bryan Cranston</item>
      <item>Alan Arkin</item>
    </actors>
    <title>Argo</title>
    <imdb_id>tt1024648</imdb_id>
  </item>
  <item>
    <actors>
      <item>Lajos Kovács</item>
      <item>Sándor Oszter</item>
    </actors>
    <title>Argo</title>
    <imdb_id>tt0297741</imdb_id>
  </item>
</IMDBDocumentList>
```

I want to retrieve the actors separately for each movie, but the following code creates an "actorList" that contains all of the actors (for both movies):

```
IEnumerable<XElement> actorList =
                from item in doc.Descendants("actors").Descendants()
                select item;
```

How can I separate the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have a class to hold these information (title and list of actors):

```
public class Movie
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public List<string> Actors { get; set; }
}
```

You can easily get `List<Movie>` from your XML using following query:

```
var movies = (from item in doc.Root.Elements("item")
              select new Movie
              {
                  Title = (string)item.Element("title"),
                  Actors = (from a in item.Element("actors").Elements("item")
                            select (string)a).ToList()
              }).ToList();
```

If you only care about actors, and don't need the titles you can get `List<List<string>>` with just actor names:

```
var actors = (from item in doc.Root.Elements("item")
              select (from a in item.Element("actors").Elements("item")
                      select (string)a).ToList()).ToList();
```